# FlexSlider dynamic vars from parent data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am using [this example](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html) of FlexSlider and I need to get the `itemWidth` from parent data attribute.

```
<div class="flexslider" data-item-width="500">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>

$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: $( this ).data( 'itemWidth' ),
    itemMargin: 5
  });
});
```

The problem is that `$( this ).data( 'itemWidth' )` gives undefined. It seems I can not access the parent data attributes. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `data-item-width` and `itemWidth`?

Comment: No sure if I got your question, but I want to get data-item-width value as `itemWidth` param in FlexSlider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.data()` only trims the first "data-" from the attribute name. It doesn't reformat it.

Also, in this context, `this` refers to `window` so it doesn't have any `data-item-width` property. Use another selector.

If you are trying to initialize multiple flexsliders with different properties, you should use `$().each` to iterate through them. In this case, you can use `this` to refer to the current `.flexslider` element.

```
$('.flexslider').each(function() {
  $(this).flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: $( this ).data( 'item-width' ),
    itemMargin: 5
  });
});
```

Comment: it does not matter, if I also change it to above codes, still it's undefined. It seems there is something wrong with $( this ). It's somehow empty

Comment: I understand this but we are instantiating several carousel with different `data-item-width` in the page and we need to refer to this carousel data attributes.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was just hoping that the FlexSlider undersnad `$(this)` since it can automatically instantiate different sliders by one call.

Comment: `this` can be a pretty tricky thing to understand in javascript. Reading this will help you a lot: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this